# How show the loader/spinner when page refresh and need to wait the authUser result in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

I have a problem, when refresh page, first of all shows `<NavigationNonAuth/>` because `authUser` the result has not come yet and in a second shows `<NavigationAuth/>`
What is the best practice to show loading when i am waiting for `authUser`

```
const Navigation = () => (

   <div>
     <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
       {authUser => (
          authUser ? <NavigationAuth/> : <NavigationNonAuth/>
       )
       }
     </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
   </div>
);

const NavigationAuth = () => (
   <nav className="navbar bg-white border btn-lg fixed-top justify-content-start p-3">
     <Link className="navbar-brand text-dark" to={ROUTES.DASHBOARD}>Dashboard</Link>
     <Link className="navbar-brand text-dark" to={ROUTES.SEARCH}>Search</Link>
     <Link className="navbar-brand text-dark" to={ROUTES.SETTINGS}>Settings</Link>
     <SignOutButton/>
   </nav>

);

const NavigationNonAuth = () => (
   <nav className="navbar bg-white btn-lg fixed-top justify-content-start p-3">
     <Link className="navbar-brand text-dark" to={ROUTES.DASHBOARD}>Landing</Link>
     <Link className="navbar-brand text-dark" to={ROUTES.SIGN_IN}>Sign In</Link>
   </nav>

);

export default Navigation;
```

context.js

```
const AuthUserContext = React.createContext(null);

export default AuthUserContext;
```

withAuthentication.js

```
const withAuthentication = Component => {
  class WithAuthentication extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        authUser: null,
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.listener = this.props.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(
         authUser => {
           authUser
              ? this.setState({ authUser })
              : this.setState({ authUser: null });
         },
      );
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      this.listener();
    }

    render() {
      return (
         <AuthUserContext.Provider value={this.state.authUser}>
           <Component {...this.props} />
         </AuthUserContext.Provider>
      );
    }
  }

  return withFirebase(WithAuthentication);
};

export default withAuthentication;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your render function do something like this:

```
constructor() {
    this.state = { isLoading: true }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({isLoading: false})
}

render() {
    return(
        this.state.isLoading ? *showLoadingScreen* : *yourPage()*
    )
}
```

Initialize isLoading as true in the constructor and false on componentDidMount